# Use original file name to save image

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library, os.walk

I want to save image with original file name for example if original file name is `hero` so the processed image name should be `hero_Zero.png`.
 I dont know how to pass file name in  `def run(dirs, img):`
Below code is correct and modified.

```
def run(dirs, img, file_):
  for (x, y) in labels:
        component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
        labels[(x, y)] = component   
        if labels[(x, y)]==0:
            Zero[y][x]=int(255)
            count=count+1
            if count<=43:
                continue
            elif count>43:
                Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
                Zeroth.save(os.path.join(dirs, file_+'Zero.png'), 'png')  
           return (labels, output_img)
def main():
    path='E:/Dataset/1/'
    for root, dirs, files in sorted(os.walk(path)):
        for file_ in files:
            #print (dirs)
           # print (files)
            full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file_)
            img = Image.open(full_file_path)
            (labels, output_img) = run(root, img, file_[:-4])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an extra argument to your function definition. Instead of just taking the directory and image, also pass the filename. The result will look like this:

```
def run(dirs, img, f_name):
  for (x, y) in labels:
        component = uf.find(labels[(x, y)])
        labels[(x, y)] = component   
        if labels[(x, y)]==0:
            Zero[y][x]=int(255)
            count=count+1
            if count<=43:
                continue
            elif count>43:
                Zeroth = Image.fromarray(Zero)
                Zeroth.save(os.path.join(dirs, f_name + '_Zero.png'), 'png')
```

Comment: i already did that  and it returns  `run() missing 1 required positional argument: 'file'` this error

Comment: how did you call the `run()` method?

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__": main()` full code is above already given

Comment: @pixelthread but nowhere in that above code is `run()` actually called... In any case, my best guess is `run(dirs, img, file[:-4])`

Comment: @pixelthread you're going to have to help me help you. I realize I made a typo in my above comment, it should have been `run(dirs, img, file_[:-4])`. If that doesn't work, you're going to have to show me the actual code where you're calling `run()` because otherwise there is no way to help

Comment: `[:-4]` is exactly the part that removes the `.png` part. For real, you're going to have to edit your question

Comment: @pixelthread the syntax error is because you're assigning the return values of `run()` to `labels` and `output_img`, but `run()` doesn't actually return a value. My best guess is that you should add one last line at the end of your function, outside all the loops: `return (labels, Zeroth)`

Comment: I'm not really sure what you want... You've already gone way past the scope of the question. If you want to ask another you can do that, but you're going to have to give much more detail about what it is you're trying to solve. I don't know which questions to ask because I don't know your code or your application

Comment: i did `return (labels, Zeroth)` but still syntax error