# How do I keep the file name of an image when resizing it and saving it to another folder?

Tags: python, neural-network, jupyter

I'm in an introductory neural networking class so mind my ignorance. Also my first SO post.

I'm trying to resize some very highly resolved images within a dataset into 80x80p grayscale images in a new dataset. However, when I do this, I'd like to keep the filenames of each new image the same as the original image. The only way I know how to resave images into a new file is through a str(count) which isn't what I want. The filenames are important in creating a .csv file for my dataset later.

The only SO post I can find that is related is this:

[Use original file name to save image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48176514/use-original-file-name-to-save-image)

But the code suggested there didn't work - wasn't sure if I was going about it the wrong way.

```py
import os
from PIL import Image
import imghdr
count=0
path1 = "/Users/..."
path2 = "/Users/..."
listing = os.listdir(path1)  
for file in listing:
    type = imghdr.what((path1 + file))
    if type == "jpeg":   
        img = Image.open("/Users/..." +file).convert('LA')
        img_resized = img.resize((80,80))
        img_resized.save(path2 + str(count) + '.png')
        count +=1
    pass
pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Reuse the original filename that you get from the for loop i.e. `file` 
and, split it into filename and extension using `os.path.splitext()` like below:

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import imghdr
count=0
path1 = "/Users/..."
path2 = "/Users/..."
listing = os.listdir(path1)  
for file in listing:
    type = imghdr.what((path1 + file))
    if type == "jpeg":   
        img = Image.open("/Users/..." +file).convert('LA')
        img_resized = img.resize((80,80))

        # splitting the original filename to remove extension
        img_filename = os.path.splitext(file)[0]
        img_resized.save(path2 + img_filename + '.png')
        count +=1
    pass
```

Another option, we can use python `str`'s built-in `split` method to split the original filename by `.` and discard the extension.

```
import os
from PIL import Image
import imghdr
count=0
path1 = "/Users/..."
path2 = "/Users/..."
listing = os.listdir(path1)  
for file in listing:
    type = imghdr.what((path1 + file))
    if type == "jpeg":   
        img = Image.open("/Users/..." +file).convert('LA')
        img_resized = img.resize((80,80))

        # splitting the original filename to remove extension
        img_filename = file.split(".")[0]
        img_resized.save(path2 + img_filename + '.png')
        count +=1
    pass
```

So, if an image has a name such as `some_image.jpeg` then, the `img_filename` will have a value `some_image` as we splitted by . and discarded `.jpeg` part of it.

**NOTE:** This option assumes the original_filename will not contain any `.` other than the extension.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that image name is on path1. If so you can grap image name from there in this way:

```
x=path1.rsplit('/',1)[1]
```

We are splitting path1 on last slash and taking image name string via indexing.